# Is there any easy way to change Arduino Wifi shield to ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266, wifi

As the title says, is there any easy way to replace WiFi shield with ESP8266, with as little as possible modification to code?

Here is my ESP:

[image: How do I display this properly?]

Comment: for the esp-01 in link, use Serial connection and AT firmware with WiFiEsp library. it is the most common option and Internet is full of tutorials

Comment: next time your question gets put on hold, please edit the question .... do not post another question

Comment: The old question was about rtpmidi, this is more general I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider porting your sketch to esp8266 board like Wemos D1. The API of the ESP8266WiFi library is same as the API of the WiFi library.

To use esp8266 as network adapter, you have two wiring options.

If you have or buy an esp8266 module with SPI pins, you can connect the esp8266 over SPI like the WiFi shield is connected. Then you upload [the WiFiSpiESP firmware](https://github.com/JiriBilek/WiFiSpiESP) to esp8266 and you include in your sketch [WiFiSpi library](https://github.com/JiriBilek/WiFiSpi) instead of WiFi library.

Second option is to connect esp8266 over Serial or SoftwareSerial. The esp8266 should have AT firmware installed. The you can include WiFiEsp library in you sketch and initialize it with the Serial interface of your choice. You can find the WiFiEsp library in Library manager. Most new esp8266 modules have AT firmware installed at default.

There is one more option for Serial connection, if WiFiEsp wouldn't work for you. [WiFiLink firmware and library](https://github.com/jandrassy/arduino-library-wifilink)

All mentioned libraries WiFiSpi, WiFiEsp and WiFiLink have the same API as the WiFi library so the rest of the code should work without changes.

Comment: I have wemos d1 uno around, should not be hard to port over. But my thesis already included mega and esp8266... So i tried to avoid them.

Comment: Anyway, will buying this solve my problem? Afaik it is mega with esp8266 as wifi inside. https://robotdyn.com/mega-wifi-r3-atmega2560-esp8266-flash-32mb-usb-ttl-ch340g-micro-usb.html

Comment: for Robotdyn Mega + WiFi the Serial option with WiFiEsp library. use dip switch setting for esp8266 on Serial 3 of Mega.

Comment: Thanks! I gonna buy robotdyn one soon. Seems easy enough.

Comment: after a while : buying robotdyn mega was one of the worst mistake I've ever made.

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan, why? the esp8266 with Mega is good. I write a new WiFiEspAT library and most of the time I work with Mega with esp8266 on Serial3. I have AT firmware in esp8266

Comment: getting esp-01 + mega counterfeit/clone in separate are far cheaper. Mine never successfully connect to wifi and the dip switch somehow very buggy (sometimes it randomly disconnects)

Comment: @RinaldoJonathan, then sorry. I don't have this board but I have other Robotdyn boards and some modules and the manufacturing quality is good with them