# Using WifiUdp.h on Arduino Mega and ESP8266?

Tags: esp8266

I was trying to run [this library](https://github.com/lathoub/Arduino-AppleMIDI-Library) on Arduino Mega, using ESP8266 as replacement of Wifi Shield, [as suggested on my older thread.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/55753/is-there-any-easy-way-to-change-arduino-wifi-shield-to-esp8266)

The problem is, I got error in compiling, after with this code :

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiEspClient.h>
#include <WiFiEspUdp.h>


#include "AppleMidi.h"
APPLEMIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(WiFiUDP, appleMIDI1);
....
```

> exit status 1
>
> 'WiFiUDP' was not declared in this scope

if I modified the code into this :

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>


#include "AppleMidi.h"
APPLEMIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(WiFiUDP, appleMIDI1);
....
```

I got this error instead

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Arduino\libraries\WiFi\src\utility\server_drv.cpp:313:40: error:
>   'WARN' was not declared in this scope
>
> ```
> WARN("error waitResponse isDataSent");
>
>                                     ^
> ```
>
> exit status 1

Full code [here at pastebin.](https://pastebin.com/K8b5J726)
I was pretty much stuck now. Please help! :(

Thanks :D

Comment: WiFiUdp.h is part of the WiFi library for the Arduino WiFi Shield. you can't use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the WiFiEsp class for UDP is `WiFiEspUDP`

```
#include <WiFiEsp.h>
#include <WiFiEspUdp.h>
#include "AppleMidi.h"

APPLEMIDI_CREATE_INSTANCE(WiFiEspUDP, AppleMIDI);
```

Comment: So I would just need to change WiFiUDP to WiFiEspUDP and I'm good to go?

Comment: yes, the macro creates an object with template type `AppleMidi_Class<WiFiEspUDP> AppleMIDI;`

Comment: gonna test this tonight. if this works, gonna accept it as answer. thanks for helping me once again :D

Comment: I used `#include "WiFiEsp.h"` and `#include "WiFiEspUdp.h"` instead and it compiled. thanks!